# Show $E[N]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(N\geqq n)$

Tags: probability

For a nonnegative and integer-valued random variable N, How can I show

$E[N]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(N\geqq n)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{N\geq k\}=\sum_{\ell=k}^\infty \mathbb P\{N=\ell\}.$$

Comment: Two of these capital N's should be lower case.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: Many thanks, I edited :-)

Comment: Would have done it myself, but apparently, I need to change/add at least six characters. :/

Answer (score 0):

This follows from Tonelli's theorem:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(N\geqslant n) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mathbb P(N=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(N=k) \sum_{n=0}^k 1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(N=k)\cdot k\\
&=\mathbb E[N].
\end{align}